# Drupal access denied error while try to login

Tags: php, jquery, html, drupal-7, access-denied

I am trying to access my website administrator in drupal but it is showing me access denied error. Here is my website URL http://www.virginiamoca.org/

I tried to login via 
http://www.virginiamoca.org/admin and http://www.virginiamoca.org/administrator

Comment: Please show the comeplete aand unadultrated error message

Comment: if its your site, then with ftp look at the directory structure

Comment: It is showing access denied. You are not authorized to access this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1) Find `base_url` in `settings.php` file 
2) it will better to configure your site in virtual host in php configuration

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience on Drupal 7, http://www.virginiamoca.org/admin will give you access denied by default as you are not logged in, So instead try to hit http://www.virginiamoca.org/user/login. This page will give you login form, But you website have some issue to render this page might be some code issue. Have a look at DBlog or apache error log, you will get some help from there